# Connection with Web-Proxy to MySql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, proxy, database-connection

I have a Program on a internal server and it needs to connect to a MySql database to retrieve some data. This server is behind a Proxy. The most libraries I found on Nuget don't have an implementation of a connection which considers proxy authentication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are we talking about socks4/5 proxies? Thats evil in C#. I've tried setting up a connection for 2 weeks without success. I will set up a bounty for this as soon as I can.

Comment: With HttpWebRequests there are no Problems. The point is that all the MySql libraries I tried do not have an implementation to add any proxy settings.

Comment: You should differenciate between a web-proxy (as used on `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`) and socks proxy, which is a hard goal to connect through in C#. Database access is (I guess) connected through TCP which cant be done via a web-proxy. So we are talking about different types of proxies for this.